Should microservices which are inside a VPC still use any form of authentication to talk to each other, like OAuth?
I have a bunch of microservices inside a VPC behind an ALB in AWS. They receive API requests from UI, hosted on CloudFront and make API calls internally.
Currently, authentication is enforced on ALB through OIDC for ALL API calls.
I am thinking to keep the auth for requests coming from UI, but not when it is coming from a MS to another MS. Since they are inside VPC, they are already protected.
Is it right ? If yes, how to achieve that ?
I thought of relaxing rules on ALB when it comes to internal communication, but did not proceed as of now.

Did you separate the API into public (coming from UI) and private (inter-microservice) endpoints? Then authentication is not necessary, imagine it as a "distributed monolith". But authorisation in each microservice still is necessary!
E.g., other solutions are to design the inter-microservice communication using some messaging queue (SQS) or event sourcing service (SNS, EventBridge) .
This AWS doc might help with the architecture: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/modernization-data-persistence/welcome.html
